# c# JSON deserialization (list that not a list)

Tags: c#, json

How can  take all items from car_items at this JSON https://app.anytimecar.ru/data/v3.4/info/  ?
I tried to:

```
public class anytimeCars
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public anytimeData data { get; set; }
}
public class anytimeCar
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string power { get; set; }
    public string exterior { get; set; }
    public string interior { get; set; }
    public string date_of_construction { get; set; }
    public string car_type { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
public class anytimeData
{
    public List<anytimeCar> car_items { get; set; }
}


anytimeCars anytimeCars = new anytimeCars();
            anytimeCars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<anytimeCars>(response.Content.ToString());
```

But it doesn't work, because car_items is not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize such a mapping to `Dictionary<int, anytimeCar>`. Note that you have to adjust your contract a bit since `car_items` is not a property in the root. It works like this:

```
public class AnytimeData
{
    [JsonProperty("car_items")]
    public Dictionary<int, anytimeCar> Cars { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public AnytimeData Data {get;set;}
}
```

And then you can make a request and deserialize it like this:

```
var url = "https://app.anytimecar.ru/data/v3.4/info/";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string json = client.DownloadString(url);
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);

    foreach (anytimeCar car in data.Data.Cars.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(car.brand);
    }
}
```